# All known steps have been taken but TLS 1.2 is still not working on Windows 7

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-7, httpclient, tls1.2

I know this is a duplicate but I have read every article on this and implemented every suggestion and yet I still can't solve it in my environment.

I am running Windows 7 Professional 64Bit - Service Pack 1

Connecting to public website that uses (taken from IE) TLS 1.2 AES with 256 bit encryption (High); ECDH with 256 bit exchange

I have set varying combinations of SCHANNEL\Protocols in the registry including

TLS 1.0\Client\Enabled=0 + DisabledByDefault=1

TLS 1.1\Client\Enabled=0 + DisabledByDefault=1

TLS 1.2\Client\Enabled=1 + DisabledByDefault=0

I have a test application that is C# using .NET Framework 4.6.1 trying both HttpClient and HttpWebRequest

'''

```
    private void cmdGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (senderX, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;            

        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(txtUrl.Text);
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";            

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

        }
        catch (Exception exRes)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
            Exception child = exRes.InnerException;

            msg.AppendLine(exRes.Message);
            while (child != null)
            {
                msg.AppendLine(child.Message);
                child = child.InnerException;
            }

            MessageBox.Show(msg.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void cmdNewGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (senderX, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(txtUrl.Text).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string output = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                        MessageBox.Show(output);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
            Exception child = ex.InnerException;

            msg.AppendLine(ex.Message);
            while(child != null)
            {
                msg.AppendLine(child.Message);
                child = child.InnerException;
            }

            MessageBox.Show(msg.ToString());
        }
    }
```

'''

No matter what registry setting combinations I try or SecurityProtocolType values I add just can't seem to force the use of TLS 1.2.

Error is always: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

What have I missed doing or what am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you installed the relevant update? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392 And may I gently suggest upgrading to a supported version of Windows

Comment: [TLS Cipher Suites in Windows 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-7) -- Some new(er) Cipher Suites are not supported in Windows 7 (and never will be, officially, since security updates stopped a while ago for non-ESU customers). -- Web Browsers bring (and handle) their own Cipher Suites.

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you for the link.  I will look into to see if this update has been applied.  And yes, we are desperate for an upgrade to OS which is in the works

Comment: @Jimi And thank you as well for the link.  I was looking for this type of answer as well to see if perhaps we are beyond a codeable fix.  I will review the cipher suites in the link to see if the new list provided to us contains these

Comment: Can't tell you for sure, but most times if you do an in-place upgrade to Windows 10, it will just use the Win7 license key

Answer (score 0):

So @Jimi comment was the correct answer.  The issue appears to be the removal of weak ciphers on the endpoint server leaving only ciphers unsupported by Windows 7.

[TLS Cipher Suites in Windows 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-7)

I apologize to @Jimi if there was a better way to have given *pronoun* credit for *pronoun* comment.